# Bash Shellshock Fix Applied But Seems that Additional Fix is Required

Tags: bash, bug-reporting

First time using this Ubuntu Forum, Not sure if this is right place to raise this issue.

Anyway, I am having a Ubuntu 14-04 VPS running.

I have applied:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
```

In the newly updated GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1) I ran:

```
env 'x=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' 'BASH_FUNC_x()=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo test"
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
%% This Line Should Not be Here: **bash: error importing function definition for `x'**
bash: error importing function definition for `BASH_FUNC_x()'
test
```

=======

%% Redhat seems has additional fixes to remove the above Line prefixed %%.

[Redhat URL showing the Additional Fixes Applied](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223)

**RHSA-2014:1306, RHSA-2014:1311 and RHSA-2014:1312**

Would be grateful if the Ubuntu Dev/ Enggr folks could take a look into the above and resolve it, if they consider the above 
relevant.

Comment: Bugs are to be reported on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net), not on [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 1):

There have been several Bash updates in Ubuntu in the past couple days. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` again, and the problem should disappear (I don't have it on my own 14.04 server).

*EDIT:* For reference, the latest version of the `bash` package in 14.04 as of right now is `4.3-7ubuntu1.4`.